# Integrating lambda value into a function

Tags: python, key-value, higher-order-functions

This is my code:

```
def empty_dic():
    return lambda x: False

def add_elem(key, value, dic):
    return lambda x: value if x == key else dic(x)

def check4key(dic, key):
    return lambda x: True if x == key else dic(x)


dic = add_elem("brand", "audemars", add_elem("colour", "blue", empty_dic()))

print(check4key(dic, "colour")("colour"))
```

In principle it works as intended, but as you can see, I need to parse the `lambda x` value in, outside of the `check4key` function parameters. This kind of defeats the purpose of my `check4key` function. Is there a way to integrate the `lambda x` into the function's parameters?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? It seems really convoluted to me.

Comment: Oh it is. Trying to pass a course is what I‘m doing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
check4key = lambda tuple: True if tuple[2] == tuple[1] else tuple[0][tuple[1]]

print(check4key(dic, "colour", "colour"))
```

That is to say, in general, you can just pass a tuple of arguments to a `lambda`, and then parse it explicitly in the `lambda` body. This starts being an edge case of whether you really want to use a lambda or a function however, which is just a question to settle on your own.